# Access object's array property with string

Tags: php

I tried to access an object property which has array form using string variable but not able do so when the string contains index selection. Take a look at this example.. what i was tring to do is to use $access3 like string

```
$dummy = new stdClass();
$dummy->testNormal = 'itemNormal';
$dummy->testArray = array('item1', 'item2');

$access1 = 'testNormal';
$access2 = 'testArray';
$access3 = 'testArray[0]';

echo 'try access1: ' . $dummy->{$access1} . '<br />';
echo 'try access2: ' . $dummy->{$access2}[0] . '<br />';
echo 'try access3: ' . $dummy->{$access3} . '<br />';
echo 'try direct: ' . $dummy->testArray[0] . '<br />';
```

The above code will return

```
try access1: itemNormal
try access2: item1
--- ERROR MESSAGE -- 
try access3:        <-- does not contain anything because of error, my expectation is it will be "item1"
try direct: item1
```

Is this impossible with php?

Comment: It's possible with eval I think, but you should forget about this approach. I'm pretty sure there are better solutions like what you would like

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done in one call. One solution can be that you split the string before the [, and call $dummy->{<<front part>>}{<<back part>>}
But you can't do testArray[0][1][2]...[n] unless you write a function which splits the string and returns the required object element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$access_handler = explode('[', $access3);
// get array name
$array_name = $access_handler[0];
// get array index
$array_index = substr($access_handler[1], 0, -1);
// call the property
echo $dummy->$array_name[$array_index];
```

you might create function for this. Otherwise you would have to use eval to evaluate your string, but that is not recommended. Also there are many ways to separate index from array name and then run it as in this example